# Допустимость фразы

Tags: выбор-слов

«Держать жизнь в безопасности». Так можно сказать? У меня большие сомнения, что да, но как перефразировать так, чтобы остался смысл, я не знаю.

Comment: Фразеологизм — это устойчивый оборот речи (он **уже есть** в языке — по определению). Ваше выражение никак к фразеологизмам не относится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*И в родном подъезде можно получить не по заслугам, а у Берингова пролива прожить всю жизнь в безопасности.* («Известия», 2002.08.02)

С потолка: *Сохранить жизнь в безопасности; Обеспечить жизнь в безопасности; Поддерживать жизнь в безопасности.*

Comment: Так **можно** ли говорить "держать жизнь в безопасности"? Вы, к сожалению, не ответили.

Comment: @ Римма Михайлова Понятно, виноват. Но не хотелось категорично приговаривать фразу, а типа «как-то не очень» — выглядит неубедительно. Автор хотел найти иной вариант изложения, сильно сомневаясь в своём: /разве/ так можно?

Answer (score 2):

Да, как-то не очень. А чем ***заботиться о своей безопасности*** не подходит?

Ещё приходит в голову ***не давать себя в обиду***, но это, согласен, подходит только в определённом аспекте.

Answer (score 2):

"**Держать жизнь** (под контролем)" - так иногда говорят даже литераторы, но не о *своей* жизни. Если не сказано, что жизнь своя, подразумевается чужая или окружающая, напр. жизнь страны - это о *власти*. Те же литераторы употребляют выражение "**держать свою жизнь** - в руках, под контролем, таким-то образом" - эти сочетания имеют если не устойчивость, то повторяемость на литературном уровне. Примеры:

> *Старайся **держать свою жизнь** так, чтобы не бояться смерти и не желать*
> *ее.* (Л. Н. Толстой, Учение о жизни - изложение в изречениях).
>
> *...учат нас следить за собой и **держать свою жизнь** в собственных*
> *руках!* (Г. Шереметева, Уроки жизни, 2019)
>
> *Я хочу Одного: **Держать свою жизнь** в руках, как тесто, которое изо
> всех сил мнут и месят, прежде чем...* (А. Камю, творчество и свобода)
>
> *Такой человек предпочитает **держать свою жизнь** под собственным
> контролем, охотно берет на себя...* (Наука и жизнь, №1, 2000)

Контекст безопасности в явном виде в таких выражениях не встречается, поэтому выражение "*держать свою жизнь в безопасности*" от непривычности воспринимается как оригинальное изречение, претендующее на поучительность. Поэтому без необходимости лучше употреблять обыденные выражения, в зависимости от контекста (*избегать риска для жизни, уделять внимание собственной безопасности, не подвергать опасности свою жизнь* и т. п.).

Answer (score 1):

*Держать жизнь* — это не сильно корректно. Жизнь ведь не держится.

Красиво звучит так:
*вести безопасный образ жизни*.
Или "*вести безопасную жизнь*".
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/244753/вести](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/244753/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)